# Change locationEngine request interval

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I'm using *mapbox* in my *App*. When building the request for my `locationEngine` I pass **20000** milliseconds, but at a certain point I need to change that interval and be notified of location changes every **5000** milliseconds.

Is there a way to change that interval, or to build another request for my `locationEngine`?

Here's what I've tried:

This is where I initialize the location engine

```
   @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void initializeLocationEngine(int interval) {
        locationEngine =LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(parentActivity);
        LocationEngineRequest request = buildEngineRequest(interval);
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, null);
        mapboxNavigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
    }
```

and when I want to change the interval I call this method:

```
  private void changeLocationEngineInterval(int interval) {
        removeLocationEngineListener();
        LocationEngineRequest request = buildEngineRequest(interval);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, null);
        mapboxNavigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The interval is a parameter of the constructor of the object, so you need to destroy the first LocationEngineRequest and create another one with the new interval you want to use.

Regards

EDIT

I put here some example code. Is a good practice to put your object as a global var, so you can access from both methods, and you can override it without delete and create again.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LocationEngineRequest request;

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void initializeLocationEngine(int interval) {
    locationEngine =LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(parentActivity);
    request = buildEngineRequest(interval);
    locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, null);
    mapboxNavigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
}

private void changeLocationEngineInterval(int interval) {
    //removeLocationEngineListener(); <-- I don't know what u doing here, but maybe you don't need
    request = buildEngineRequest(interval);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, null);
    mapboxNavigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank`s Juan, i tried to destroy the object, but i couldn`t. Could you provide some code please?

Comment: Thank`s again Juan! I`ve implemented your code but i figured out something new. Can it be that my locationEngine is never set to my MapboxNavigation Object if i am not in navigation mode? I`m just showing the position of the marker in the map.
And even if i initialize my locationEngine for the firstTime with an interval of 10000 miliseconds, it always updates my location every 20000